# jQuery Button resize on hover

Tags: jquery, button, resize

I'm trying to code a button which resizing its width on hover.

Initial state:
 - play sign as a background (position center center)

State hover:
 - play should go to the left ( position left center) - it works !
 - some caption appears in the center of resized area (I use here opacity)

This is made only with CSS  - transition feature.

Everything is fine expect for the moment when I move out mouse cursor from the button, that is the background (play sign) immediately goes to position of center center.

I want to do this after the animation is finished not at the very begining.

This is my code

HTML:

```
<article class="buttons clearfix">
    <div id="play"><a href="#" class="hide">Click</a></div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
   .buttons #play {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer; }
   buttons #play:hover {
      outline: 1px solid #84bd21; }

  .buttons #play {
    background: #019c43 url(http://i57.tinypic.com/ji10l3.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out; }

    .buttons #play:hover {
      width: 200px;
      background: #019c43 url(http://i57.tinypic.com/ji10l3.png) no-repeat left center; }

    .buttons #play a {
        text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      display: block;
      line-height: 50px;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
      transition: opacity 0.3s linear; }
      .buttons #play a:hover {
        opacity: 1; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3p0n66b/57

I use also jQuery methods hover, animation, delay but the effect (also used callback function) is similar the background immediately goes to center center position on mouse leave.

Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed duplicated background rule (the one from `:hover`), and instead of `center center` I put `10px center`:

```
background: #019c43 url(http://i57.tinypic.com/ji10l3.png) no-repeat 10px center;
```

Demo:

```css
.buttons #play {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
buttons #play:hover {
    outline: 1px solid #84bd21;
}
.buttons #play {
    background: #019c43 url(http://i57.tinypic.com/ji10l3.png) no-repeat 10px center;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.buttons #play:hover {
    width: 200px;
}
.buttons #play a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
.buttons #play a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<article class="buttons clearfix">
    <div id="play"><a href="#" class="hide">Click</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: That is a good solution! But i found another maybe small problem. When I set line-height=height of div to center vertically the caption the area below "a" makes longer from 50-100px, so the clickable area becomes also below the link. Do you know how to remove it? (without line-height is ok)

Comment: @kuba0506 Add the jsfiddle. It's hard to debug using comments. :-)

Comment: I think it's a browser bug, because in jsfiddle this seems to work fine, so thx again for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I changed the arrow to be fixed to the Left (notice the 10px in the backgroud rule).

```
.buttons #play {
background: #019c43 url(http://i57.tinypic.com/ji10l3.png) no-repeat 10px center;
text-align: center;
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out; }
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3p0n66b/59/